# convert 12 hour time format to 24 hours format from python

Tags: python

from my python code, I got the resulted list like below.

```
list1 = [{'start': 'Mon12', 'end': '3:30'}, {'start': '7', 'end':
'10:30'}]
```

Here, i need to convert the above list1 to 24 hrs date format like below.

```
list2 = [{'start': 12, 'end': 1530}, {'start': 1900, 'end': 2230}]
```

How to do this in python?

Comment: how you will distinguish that '3:30' is '15:30' not '3:30'?

Comment: Should list1 really contain 'Mon12', or should it just be '12'?

Comment: it should contain 'Mon12'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should probably distinguish between am/pm as mentioned in the comments above.

However if you knew all these times were pm, suggested by your output list above, then you could iterate through each value stripping unwanted characters and add 1200, as shown below:

```
list1 = [{'start' : 'Mon12', 'end' : '3:30'},
     {'start' : '7', 'end' : '10:30'}]

def shift24(listofdict):
    shift = 1200
    resultlist = listofdict
    # loop through list of dictionaries, then through each dictionary
    for d in resultlist:
        for key in d:

        # create a mask by stripping each value of numbers
        # (uses a list comp of numerical ASCII characters)

        mask = d[key].strip(''.join([chr(x) for x in range(48,58)]))

        # use that mask to get just the numbers

        maskstrip = d[key].replace(mask,'')

        # evaluate the length of string and convert to right format
        # assuming if len(str) < 3: we just have the hours and need
        # to mulitply by 100

        if len(maskstrip) < 3: 
            result = ('%04d' % (int(maskstrip) * 10**2))
        else:
            result = ('%04d' % int(maskstrip))

        # shift these values by 1200 hours and return list
        #use str() if you want to output strings not integers

        d[key] = int(result) + shift

    return resultlist

print(shift24(list1))
```

The output would be:

```
[{'start': 2400, 'end': 1530}, {'start': 1900, 'end': 2230}]
```

Hope that helps, change as to what suits your needs